# PostgreSQL Bitwise operators with bit varying "cannot AND bit strings of different sizes"

Tags: postgresql, bit-manipulation

I have a varying bitmask field and I want to perform a bitwise AND on it.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  cannot AND bit strings of different sizes
SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"  WHERE (read_roles_bitmask = B'0' OR read_roles_bitmask & B'10' > B'0')
```

( you need to have bitmasks with varying lengths in your table to get this error. )

I'm expecting the bitwise math to look like the following:
00010 & 100000010 = 00010

I've also tried casting the bitmask to a integer with no luck.

Why does PostgreSQL choke on this?

How should I rewrite this query to play nicely?

I was able to use the following to get bitwise operators working:
lpad(read_roles_bitmask::varchar,64,'0')::bigint

However this is limited to 64 bits, is there a better way?

Comment: This is a weird limitation. I'd expect Pg's `&` to left-extend the smaller operand with zeroes automatically.

Comment: @Craig: The "must be the same size" behavior is documented. Also, `B'10'::bit(1)` is `B'1'` and `B'1'::bit(2)` is `B'10'` so bits go left-to-right. I get the impression that the bit order changed somewhere along the line so perhaps they force you to be explicit to avoid version issues.

Comment: It's documented, but frankly it's pretty useless to right-extend bit fields and offer no left-extend option either implicitly or explicitly. Who uses left-to-right bit strings?

Comment: With the `read_roles_bitmask & B'10' > B'0'` part, you just want to see if bit-2 (from right to left, 1-based counting) is `1`, right? If your bits when left-to-right then you could cast to `bit(2)` to grab just the 2 left-most bits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour of the PostgreSQL `bit` and `bit varying` types is exceedingly unhelpful, with the way it refuses to extend bitfields for operations, and it right-extends them for casts instead of left-extending them.

It would make sense for Pg to left-extend the smaller operand with zeroes before an AND or OR operation, rather than failing.

You can't use  a cast to `bit(n)` to get the same lengths, because for some insane reason a cast to `bit(n)` *right-pads* the argument, making it useless in almost all situations.

You can use something like `lpad($1::text, greatest(length($1), length($2)),'0')::bit varying` to left-extend a bit field with zeroes to the greater of two lengths. It's cumbersome, but it'll work. I'd recommend writing wrapper functions to contain the mess.

Alternately, consider modifying the `bit` support code in `src/backend/utils/adt/varbit.c` to add functions to left-extend and left-truncate bit fields, and functions to do left-extending comparisons. It should be pretty easy based on the existing code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue today. I wanted to do almost exactly the same thing: mask off the least significant two bits of a bitstring and compare the result with a literal value, like this:

```
status & b'11' > b'01'
```

(status was my bit varying column).

Initially I tried using Craig's solution, but it got pretty messy pretty quickly because not only does the mask have to be left extended, so does the value I was comparing the result with, since according to postgresql:

```
t2=> select b'0010' < b'01';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

The RHS is right padded to make it the same size as the LHS before applying the `<` operation.

In the end I solved it like this:

```
(status << length(status)-2)::bit(2) > b'01'
```

The nice thing about that is it allows you to extract any set of bits for comparison. For example to get the pair of bits 3rd from the left:

```
(status << length(status)-6)::bit(2)
```

You can also use `substring` to extract an arbitrary set of bits for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

1) as mentioned in other answers -

```
postgres has has some inconvenient/counterintuitive behaviors - 
right padding when casting to bit(n), 
bitwise ops only on similar size,
etc.
```

2) one workaround is -

```
double-casting every value - to integer and then to bit(XX)
```

pros:

```
- left vs right padding works correctly 
- all the bit-strings have same length for correct bitwise operations
- comparisons work correctly
- bit-masking/casting to get least significant bits
```

examples:

basic left padding:

```
select B'0010'::int::bit(22)
0000000000000000000010
```

bitwise ops:

```
select B'0010'::int::bit(22) | B'01'::int::bit(22)
0000000000000000000011
```

comparison:

```
select B'0010'::int::bit(22) > B'01'::int::bit(22)
true
```

bit-masking/casting to get three LEAST significant bits:

```
select B'11010'::int::bit(3)
010
```

bit-masking/casting to get three MOST significant bits:

```
select B'11010'::bit(3)
110
```

**UPDATE:**
use int8 to accommodate longer bit-strings