# bit varying in Postgres to be queried by sub-string pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, bitmask

The following Postgres table contains some sample content where the binary data is stored as bit varying (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-bit.html):

```
ID   |   Binary data
----------------------
1    |    01110        
2    |    0111       
3    |    011         
4    |    01        
5    |    0         
6    |    00011      
7    |    0001        
8    |    000    
9    |    00          
10   |    0  
11   |    110
12   |    11
13   |    1
```

Q: Is there any query (either native SQL or as Postgres function) to return all rows where the binary data field is equal to *all* sub-strings of the target bit array. To make it more clear lets look at the example search value **01101**:

1. 01101 -> no result
2. 0110 -> no result
3. 011 -> 3
4. 01 -> 4
5. 0 -> 5, 10

The result returned should contain the rows: 3, 4, 5 and 10.

Edit:
The working query is (thanks to Laurenz Albe):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '01101' LIKE (table.binary_data::text || '%')
```

Furthermore I found this discussion about Postgres bit with fixed size vs bit varying helpful:
[PostgreSQL Bitwise operators with bit varying "cannot AND bit strings of different sizes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694129/postgresql-bitwise-operators-with-bit-varying-cannot-and-bit-strings-of-differe)

Comment: Please set up a db/sql fiddle with sample data so the types are clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
WHERE '01101' LIKE (col2::text || '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for bitwise and:

```
where col2 & B'01101' = col2
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with 'SELECT * from test where test.binary_data & B'01101' = test.binary_data' result: Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  cannot AND bit strings of different sizes